# ACR122U Reading Chip card UID status

Tags: c#, nfc, acr122

I use an NFC reader / writer ACR122U

Creating program in c # with ACR122u and WINSCARD.DLL and this library https://github.com/h4kbas/nfc-reader
I would need to know if it is possible for the reader to find out whether the block with the UID of the card is rewritable or not. How to find out? I need the value to return true or false.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to try and write to the block with the UID, if there is no error on write and it has taken your new value it is (was) rewritable.

Comment: What is the exact way to do this?

Comment: The library you referenced has instructions on how to `write` to the card and looks like it will throw an exception if it fails, You don't give enough details of the NFC card make and model to give more precise instructions

Comment: When i try write to block 0, function always return true.